# Ruby version upgrade in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed railsinstaller with ruby 2.3.3 and now i need to upgrade the ruby version from 2.3.3 to 2.4.2. I downloaded and added ruby 2.4.2 through settings(Ruby sdk and gems). but when I ruby -v command i still shows 2.3.3. I am using windows machine.The latest railsinstaller version contains ruby 2.3.3 only.How can I upgrade ?
              [image]

Comment: You should take a look at RVM or Rbenv if you need multiple versions of Ruby on the same machine. I believe there are Windows ports of one or both of these tools. Alternatively, can you uninstall the older version?

Comment: ^ What he said. Either uninstall the old version, or use a version management tool like `rvm` (Ruby Version Manager). But to be honest, if this is at all possible, I would strongly advise you to *not use Windows* -- you'll encounter all sorts of annoying issues like this, which are much more easily resolved on a unix machine.